# How to Call This Java Program in PL/SQL

Tags: java, java-stored-procedures

I have a Java Program which shows the List of Ports available in my system.

This program running fine at Command Prompt. But Now i want to use this Java program through PL/SQL.

But i am facing error as attached.

Spend Lot of time But can't Success.

Below is my Java Program.

```
import javax.comm.*;
import java.util.*;

/** List all the ports available on the local machine. **/
public class TestPorts
{
public static void main (String args[])
{

Enumeration port_list = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

while (port_list.hasMoreElements())
{
CommPortIdentifier port_id = (CommPortIdentifier)port_list.nextElement();

if (port_id.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL)
{
System.out.println ("Serial port: " + port_id.getName());
}
else if (port_id.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_PARALLEL)
{
System.out.println ("Parallel port: " + port_id.getName());
}
else
System.out.println ("Other port: " + port_id.getName());
}
} // main
} // class PortList[enter image description here][1]

D:\>loadjava -u hr1/hr1@orcl -v -resolve TestPorts.java
arguments: '-u' 'hr1/hr1@orcl' '-v' '-resolve' 'TestPorts.java'
creating : source TestPorts
loading  : source TestPorts
resolving: source TestPorts
errors   : source TestPorts
    ORA-29535: source requires recompilation
    TestPorts:10: cannot resolve symbol
    symbol  : variable CommPortIdentifier
    location: class TestPorts
    Enumeration port_list = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
                            ^
    TestPorts:14: cannot resolve symbol
    symbol  : class CommPortIdentifier
    location: class TestPorts
    CommPortIdentifier port_id = (CommPortIdentifier)port_list.nextElement();
    ^
    TestPorts:14: cannot resolve symbol
    symbol  : class CommPortIdentifier
    location: class TestPorts
    CommPortIdentifier port_id = (CommPortIdentifier)port_list.nextElement();
                                  ^
    TestPorts:16: cannot resolve symbol
    symbol  : variable CommPortIdentifier
    location: class TestPorts
    if (port_id.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL)
                                 ^
    TestPorts:20: cannot resolve symbol
    symbol  : variable CommPortIdentifier
    location: class TestPorts
    else if (port_id.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_PARALLEL)
                                      ^
    5 errors
The following operations failed
    source TestPorts: resolution
exiting  : Failures occurred during processing

D:\>
```

Comment: The ideal way of doing this is using Javaload to load the java class to Oracle database and execute as a [Java Stored Procedures](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14187/chfive.htm)

Comment: First, compile the class to make sure that there are no errors, then use the switch to load and compile the class file. And make sure all necessary JAR files are loaded as well to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to run .class file instead of .java

- firstly compile your java class using javac TestPorts.java (its output is TestPorts.class)
- loadjava -u hr1/hr1@orcl -v -resolve TestPorts.class

Answer (score 0):

javax.comm is not part of standard JDK so you need to add it manually using the `ojvmtc` tool before running `loadjava`, see [ojvmtc tool doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/jjdev/ojvmtc-tool.html#GUID-708836F1-6003-484E-9AAC-8A6BF24362C7)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly let’s check  CommPortIdentifier.class on database.

As SYS:
SELECT object_name, status FROM dba_objects 
WHERE object_type like '%JAVA%' and dbms_java.longname(object_name) like '% CommPortIdentifier%';

If no rows selected, you can try to load needed jar library which contains CommPortIdentifier.class by using loadjava?
Then compile your code again on database.